# How to trade code for Access Token using owin

Tags: owin, identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server 4 V3 and a .Net Framework V4.6 with Owin client. I'm trying to implement the `authroization_code` flow, but cannot figure out how to trade the code supplied by Identity Server for an access and id token. How can I do this in the following event handler:

```
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                {
                    var code = context.Code;
                    //Now what?
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `Configuration` Method in `Startup.cs` I needed the following settings:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ...
            ResponseType = "code",
            RedeemCode = true,
            ...
            
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seen in doc :
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html?highlight=grant_type%3D%22code%22#example

```
POST /connect/token

client_id=client1&
client_secret=secret&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=hdh922&
redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/callback
```

Comment: Thanks, I have this call working but because it is not being done through owin, when I query HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated it is false.

Comment: @Josh are you in a webforms or MVC app ? Once you retrieved the access Token you need to call the /connect/userinfo enpoint to obtain the user info and build the identity on app side. Then Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(). Look at this tutorial : https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I have figured this out. Owin has a setting within OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions class called RedeemCode. This seems to be a magic setting that does all the code swapping for you!